# Ошибка : OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/dir/04/12/21/15:10:33'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Перепробовал абсолютно всё и raw текст и экранированый слеш , везде эта ошибка

вот код

```
import time
i = "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/HOODLUM/1293830/remote/User_57351E109.ProfileData"
dir_1 = "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/dir/"
dir_1 += time.strftime("%x") + "/" + time.strftime("%X")
f1 = open(i , "rb")
f2 = open(dir_1 , "wb")
f2.write(f1.read())
```

Comment: У вас в имени файла (в конце, где время) стоят двоеточия. Имя файла не должно содержать двоеточие. Под windows двоеточие в пути файла допустимо только после буквы диска

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка здесь:

```
dir_1 += time.strftime("%x") + "/" + time.strftime("%X")
```

точнее в выражении `time.strftime("%X")`, которое возвращает время в виде с двоеточиями.

Измените (в имени файла запрещенное) двоеточие чем-то другим, например точкой:

```
dir_1 += time.strftime("%x") + "/" + time.strftime("%X").replace(":", ".")
```

---

*Замечание:*

Для работы с путями лучше применить модуль `os.path`:

```
import os.path

dir_1 += os.path.join(time.strftime("%x"), time.strftime("%X").replace(":", ".")
```

Тогда вам не нужно заниматься присутствием или правильным количеством символов `/` или `\`.